# Using a variable from controller in model in PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, pagination

I want to use the variable `$page1` from my controller in my model but I receive the message

> "undefinded variable : page1 in articles_model"

Now, my question is: how could I declare this variable in order to be usable and recognized by the model?

MY controller

```
   <?php

require MODELS . "articles_model.php";


class Articles {

    function index() {

        $articlesModel = new ArticlesModel();
        $articles = $articlesModel->getAll();
        $art = $articlesModel->getArticlesByLimit();


        $page =$_GET['page'];

        if($page==""||$page=="1") {
          $page1 = 0;
        } else {
          $page1 = ($page*5)-5;
        }


        $cou = count($art);
        $x = $cou/5;
        $x = ceil($x);
```

My model

```
<?php
require_once "db_model.php";

class ArticlesModel extends DB {

     function getAll() {
      $statement = $this->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM articles");
      return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    function getArticlesByLimit() {
        $statement = $this->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM articles limit $page1,5");
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: class Articles {
       $public $page1 = 0;
    function index() {
        
        $articlesModel = new ArticlesModel();
        $articles = $articlesModel->getAll();
        $art = $articlesModel->getArticlesByLimit();


        $page =$_GET['page'];

        if($page==""||$page=="1") {
          $this->page1 = 0;
        } else {
          $this->page1 = ($page*5)-5;
        }


        $cou = count($art);
        $x = $cou/5;
        $x = ceil($x);

Comment: Why not declaring the variable in hour model method as is : getArticlesByLimit($page) then pass it from your controller : $articlesModel->getArticlesByLimit(1); for page 1...?

Comment: It doesen't working...none of these 2 described above...

Comment: Instead of trying to pass individual values between major components of the system. i.e. controller, model and then view. Have you considered using a 'Data Transfer Object'? It can hold a state indicator about the validity of the data, as well as validated values and error messages. It has no logic and really should be immutable. imo, It is useful though.

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER

```
<?php

require MODELS . "articles_model.php";


class Articles {

    function index() {

        $articlesModel = new ArticlesModel();
        $articles = $articlesModel->getAll();


        $page =$_GET['page'];

        if($page==""||$page=="1") {
          $page1 = 0;
        } else {
          $page1 = ($page*5)-5;
        }




        $art = $articlesModel->getArticlesByLimit($page1);
        $cou = count($art);
        $x = $cou/5;
        $x = ceil($x);
```

MODEL

```
<?php
require_once "db_model.php";

class ArticlesModel extends DB {

     function getAll() {
      $statement = $this->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM articles");
      return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    function getArticlesByLimit($page1) {
        $statement = $this->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM articles limit $page1,5");
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: Wish to clarify your answer what your code does differently?